# Automatically load content into a created div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, django

I'm looking for a way to have jquery automatically change the content of a `<div>` upon its creation in a page.

What I'm doing, specifically, is to use jquery to load django templates into the page. Some of those templates contain s that I want to immediately alter as soon as they come into the browser.

As a simple example, what I'd like is for the following to work:

```
$(".load_into").live("load",function(){$(this).html("Dynamic content!");});
```

However, "load" isn't an eventtype that can be used with `<div>`s, so that doesn't actually work. Any thoughts on simple ways to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: does the div creation happen on page loading or can it happen any moment?

Comment: I think you'd be better off having the code that creates the div also populate it.  This doesn't seem like an instance where binding to an event is really called for.

Comment: It can happen at any moment, so $(document).ready() happens before the div is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want here is the [`livequery` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), using it would look like this:

```
$(".load_into").livequery(function(){
  $(this).html("Dynamic content!");
});
```

Unlike [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which listens for events, [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) looks for new elements, and will run the function you give it on all new elements as it finds them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that, sounds promising.

Comment: Livequery did exactly what I needed it to do. I'm sure that there's an inefficiency aspect to it, but for my use, it's negligible. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @wdahab - Definitely true about your concerns, but it's the best available option I'm aware of, and welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for the ready-callback function

```
$(".load_into").ready(function(){$(this).html("Dynamic content!");});
```

this will **not** run after the div is created in the browser
**the common way would be to tie this callback to the document creation:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".load_into").html("Dynamic content!");});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear on my part, the div that I want to automatically modify is loaded into the page after $(document).ready() has been called.

Comment: @sje397: corrected

@wdahab: then I don't know of any solutions, sry